# XPages view data source and limit to single category

Tags: xpages, datasource, categories

I have a categorized view that I am using as a view data source in an XPage. I have set the  categoryFilter of the data source so that only the call history of the selected individual (for a given incident) is displayed. The filter being stored in the sessionScope is a concatenation of the UniqueID of the person and the IncidentID. The lookup view is categorized by that value.

One would expect that to work, however the filtering does not seem to be working and I can see all call histories regardless of the person I choose. I've done this before and I must be missing something obvious.

I have verified the sessionScope.callHistoryID is being updated as I select a new person. My Call History db currently only has 2 history documents for one guest, yet they display for every guest in the Xpage.

[image]

sessionScope.callHistoryID from the debugger is obviously not the same (see below):

[image]

```
<xp:panel id="pnlCallHistoryModal" style="padding-bottom:20px">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="callhistoryView"
        viewName="luCallHistorybyPaxandIncidentID"
        databaseName="blah.nsf"
        ignoreRequestParams="true"
        categoryFilter="#{javascript:sessionScope.callHistoryID}">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 panel-body">
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{callhistoryView}"
                var="viewRow" indexVar="rowIndex" rows="500"
                repeatControls="false">
                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="header"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                <tbody>]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:text disableTheme="true" xp:key="footer"
                        escape="false">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
                                </tbody>
                                </table>]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:this.facets>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#    {javascript:if(viewRow.isCategory()){
return false
}else{
return true
}}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                    <xp:td styleClass="col-md-10 col-lg-10 small">
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="name">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ProperCase(viewRow.getColumnValue("CallerFullName"))}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                        <br></br>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                            styleClass="small secondary-text">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(viewRow.getColumnValue("CallerMemo").length > 128){
return viewRow.getColumnValue("CallerMemo").substring(0,128) + " ..."
}else{
return viewRow.getColumnValue("CallerMemo")
}}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="col-md-2 col-lg-2 small">
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="creationdatetime"
                            styleClass="small">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewRow.getColumnValue("CallDateTime")}]]></xp:this.value>
                            <xp:this.converter>
                                <xp:convertDateTime type="both"
                                    dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short">
                                </xp:convertDateTime>
                            </xp:this.converter>
                    </xp:text>                          
                    </xp:td>    
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:repeat>
        </div>
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this will be doing the equivalent of `ViewNavigator.createViewNavFromCategory()`. It's worth checking how that acts if the category name doesn't exist. It may fall back to a partial match.

For "restrict to category", you might be better placed using the `keys` property and settings `keysExactMatch` to true.

Comment: Paul, I just tried that. Still get the same results.

<xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoView var="callhistoryView"
   viewName="luCallHistorybyPaxandIncidentID"
   databaseName="blah.nsf"
   ignoreRequestParams="true"
   keys="#{javascript:sessionScope.callHistoryID}"
   keysExactMatch="true">
  </xp:dominoView>
 </xp:this.data>

Comment: Paul,

I suppose I should mention that the code I posted above is in a modal that is being opened when I click on the row of a repeat control.

I found that when I moved that code to a new test XPage, it works just fine. What could be the reason?

It  seems like the modal is being opened before the session.Scope is being updated so the view is populated by the previous key.

Comment: I would expect that the launching of the modal will need to trigger a partial refresh to update the sessionScoppe variable, then the datasource would need to be in the refresh area.